# Breaking out of follow mode with less and journalctl

Tags: less, journalctl

An interesting annoyance that just plagued a coworker:

If you `less` a file that's being appended to, you can hit <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> to start following the output stream in real time. Then, to stop following the output, you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, after which you can navigate and search the file as usual.

This does not work when using `journalctl`. Say you want to follow your nginx log - you'd run `journalctl -u nginx`, and then the usual <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> to start following the output. However, when you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, `less` immediately terminates, rather than exiting the "follow" mode and returning to "navigation" mode as it does when following a file.

Needless to say, this is incredibly annoying. Why is this, and how do I restore the normal functionality?

Comment: It's because of the default options that `systemd` passes to `less` (see `man journalctl` section _Environment_)... Same question as [here](http://serverfault.com/a/785611)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As answered over on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/785611), this is because `less` is invoked with the `K` flag, which causes it to die upon recieving a `^C` character, rather than returning to its command prompt.

To remedy this, export the variable `SYSTEMD_LESS="FRSXM"` into your environment. This is the standard set of flags that `systemd` passes to `less`, minus the problematic `K` that makes it impossible to break out of follow mode.

Comment: With systemd 241 on Debian 10. I had to set **both** `SYSTEMD_PAGER='less -FRSXM'` and `SYSTEMD_LESS='FRSXM'`.